# Need help discarding all changes in VS Code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I haven't used VS Code on this one PC in a long time and last time I did, I messed up something with the git upload where it tried and failed to upload a ridiculous number of sub files to GitHub. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the application as well as disconnected and reconnected GitHub but yet all those commits still show up in the Source Control. I want to remove them all and start fresh. When I select Discard Changes for one or all the files I am getting this error:

```
fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born
```

What can I do to remove all of these from VS Code? It's for a new GitHub account too.

Comment: if you want to start new in a project folder, delete the `.git` folder, also remove the github project, after you have secured the files you want to keep from the repo

Comment: The message means what it says: you're on a non-existent branch. Most likely, you're working in a completely empty Git repository, so there's nothing you can do *with* Git yet. Everything you're doing is strictly a VSCode thing. (But I'd need to see output from `git branch` and `git status` to be sure.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to delete the .vscode folder in C:\Users<USER>.vscode